# Getting the TIB/TEB of a Thread by it's Thread Handle (2015)

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, process, handle

since most links to this particular issue on http://undocumented.ntinternals.net are apparently dead and the NtQueryInfoThread along with relevant THREADINFOCLASSes has vanished from the Winternl.h I am now sitting here struggling to find the TEB of a process that I know the handle of.
I tried loading the method from the ntdll.dll, which was another solution that seemed to work but sadly I still fail to get the desired address.

```
typedef NTSTATUS(*ThreadInfoProc)(HANDLE, THREADINFOCLASS, PVOID, ULONG,  PULONG);
PVOID CProcessHelper::GetThreadStackTopAddress(HANDLE hThread)
{
HINSTANCE ntdllInstance;
ThreadInfoProc NtQueryInfoThread;

ntdllInstance = LoadLibrary("Ntdll.dll");

if (ntdllInstance != NULL)
{
    NtQueryInfoThread = (ThreadInfoProc)GetProcAddress(ntdllInstance, "NtQueryInformationThread");

    if (NtQueryInfoThread != NULL)
    {

        THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION bi;
        NT_TIB tib;

        NTSTATUS ntstat = 0;
        NTSTATUS ntstat = (NtQueryInfoThread)(hThread, (THREADINFOCLASS)0, &bi, sizeof(THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION),NULL);

        ReadProcessMemory(CurrentProcessHandle, bi.TebBaseAddress, &tib, sizeof(NT_TIB), 0);

        PrintHex(tib.StackBase); // output: CCCCCCCCCC
    }
}

return nullptr;
}
```

Is there any other way, perhaps using public api calls to get the TEB of a thread? (As MSDN states that this approach should not be used any longer.)

Best Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine :S The only other way to get the TEB of a thread is to read it using:

`NT_TIB* tib = (NT_TIB*)__readfsdword(0x18);`

and read the base address from that.

Your calls may be failing because you might not have the right permissions to read the memory. Try using `VirtualProtect`?

The below works but I've only tested it on the current process..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

typedef LONG NTSTATUS;
typedef DWORD KPRIORITY;
typedef WORD UWORD;

typedef struct _CLIENT_ID
{
    PVOID UniqueProcess;
    PVOID UniqueThread;
} CLIENT_ID, *PCLIENT_ID;

typedef struct _THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION
{
    NTSTATUS                ExitStatus;
    PVOID                   TebBaseAddress;
    CLIENT_ID               ClientId;
    KAFFINITY               AffinityMask;
    KPRIORITY               Priority;
    KPRIORITY               BasePriority;
} THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PTHREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION;

enum THREADINFOCLASS
{
    ThreadBasicInformation,
};

void* GetThreadStackTopAddress(HANDLE hProcess, HANDLE hThread)
{
    bool loadedManually = false;
    HMODULE module = GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll");

    if (!module)
    {
        module = LoadLibrary("ntdll.dll");
        loadedManually = true;
    }

    NTSTATUS (__stdcall *NtQueryInformationThread)(HANDLE ThreadHandle, THREADINFOCLASS ThreadInformationClass, PVOID ThreadInformation, ULONG ThreadInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength);
    NtQueryInformationThread = reinterpret_cast<decltype(NtQueryInformationThread)>(GetProcAddress(module, "NtQueryInformationThread"));

    if (NtQueryInformationThread)
    {
        NT_TIB tib = {0};
        THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION tbi = {0};

        NTSTATUS status = NtQueryInformationThread(hThread, ThreadBasicInformation, &tbi, sizeof(tbi), nullptr);
        if (status >= 0)
        {
            ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, tbi.TebBaseAddress, &tib, sizeof(tbi), nullptr);

            if (loadedManually)
            {
                FreeLibrary(module);
            }
            return tib.StackBase;
        }
    }


    if (loadedManually)
    {
        FreeLibrary(module);
    }

    return nullptr;
}

void __stdcall Test()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("Hi. ");
        Sleep(500);
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::cout<<GetThreadStackTopAddress(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentThread())<<"\n";

    DWORD threadID = 0;
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(Test), nullptr, 0, &threadID);
    std::cout<<GetThreadStackTopAddress(GetCurrentProcess(), hThread)<<"\n\n";
    CloseHandle(hThread);
    Sleep(7000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I read through your code and noticed a few mistakes in my own. One unrelated but crucial mistake of mine was that I still had the winternal.h included. When I tried to declare THREADINFOCLASS again I was receiving type-errors (hence the cast in my first attempt) 

I also noticed that NTSTATUS returned 0xc000008 in many cases before, which honestly should have been the first thing I check... So apparently I also had a mistake in the way I get handles from other processes which resulted in a bunch of invalid thread handles.

Thanks!